# Are there natural languages with the following properties (seen in Esperanto)?

Tags: linguistic-typology, list-of-languages, articles, declension, esperanto

Are there natural languages that have the following set of properties:

- The language possesses nouns, adjectives, and definite articles
- Nouns and adjective are both inflected for number and case (or at least one of the categories) and show agreement
- The definite article is **not** inflected, but is invariable

This set of features is present in Esperanto:

la bela virino / la belaj vironoj / la belan virinon/ la belajn virinojn  "the beautiful woman" / "the beautiful women" (Nom. Sg. /Nom. Pl. /Acc. Sg. /Acc. Pl.)

It is different from the behaviour of articles and adjectives in the standard average European languages: Either both articles and adjectives are inflected, or both aren't.

Comment: Curious choice of properties. Is there any motivation for this particular choice? Any reason to desire this set of features?

Comment: @Mitch Curious, indeed. I always wondered about this particular feature of Esperanto, and this question is mainly curiosity-driven.

Comment: I think it's probably related to the fact that Zamenhof lived in a slavic linguistical zone, he was polish, and the slavic languages, probably a good part of them, don't have grammatical articles, or have only one, so, articles weren't so interesting for him, it would be like he thought that just a simple article would make the job, since the language is not based solely on the slavic branch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generalising from [fdb's answer about Arabic](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/23163/17305) and [postmortes' answer about Maltese](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/23171/17305): there are several languages in the Semitic family that have these three properties. Inflected nouns and adjectives are in Proto-Semitic, but definiteness was not a morphological category at that stage. However, some languages developed prefixes and suffixes for this purpose (Hebrew, Arabic, Aramaic, Amharic):

> Definiteness seems not to have been a morphological category of Proto-Semitic. Akkadian does not indicate definiteness at all, and Ge'ez only in an incipient or covert way. In those languages which do have a definite article, the formal variation is striking. The article, though always affixal, is a prefix in some languages, a suffix in others. Thus Hebrew has the prefix *ha-*, Arabic has the prefix *al-*, whereas Aramaic uses the suffix *-ā* and South Arabian has the suffix *-n*. Amharic has innovated a new definite suffix *-u* from the old 3sg possessive clitic ‘his’ (see 2.). Nouns which have a pronominal possessive suffix, or which occur in the Construct form (and thus take a following dependent genitive), do not take the article. An indefinite article is found only in Arabic, where its suffixal form (nunation: *-n*) contrasts with the prefixal definite article *al-*, so that ‘definiteness’ is expressed in two different slots:
>
> > *al-kitābu* ‘the book’ vs. *kitābu-n* ‘a book’.
>
> (Note that *-n* is an indefinite marker in Arabic, but a definite marker in South Arabian.)

<sup>Weninger, S., Watson, J. E., Streck, M. P., & Khan, G. (2011). The Semitic Languages: An International Handbook. Berlin: De Gruyter Mouton.</sup>

Hence, it appears that the definite article has been a separate development in several branches of West Semitic (at least Arabian, North-West Semitic and Ethiosemitic). However, Amharic [inflects the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amharic#Definiteness) so the non-inflected definite article seems to be restricted to Central Semitic.

Answer (score 8):

> - The language possesses nouns, adjectives, and a definite article
> - Nouns and adjectives are both inflected for number and case and show agreement
> - The definite article is not inflected, but is invariable for gender, number and case.

Arabic fits these criteria.

Comment: Just a friendly advice, but I'd expect this answer can be expanded by showing the examples that fulfill the criteria.

Answer (score 5):

[Welsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_Welsh_morphology#The_article) is another such language, to some extent at least.

Nouns and adjectives do not inflect for case; most nouns and a subset of adjectives inflect for number; the majority of adjectives do not inflect for number, though. All adjectives inflect for gender.

There is no indefinite article, but there is a definite article. The definite article has three different forms, but like English /ə ~ ən/ and /ðə ~ ði/, the forms are based on phonological environment, not morphological form:

- If the following word begins with a vowel sound (including /j/ and /h/, but not /w/), the article is ***yr***
- If the following word begins with a consonant sound (including /w/), the article is ***y***
- If the article follows a word that ends in a vowel sound, regardless of what the following begins with, the article is ***’r***

Using Wikipedia’s examples of the nouns *bwrdd* (m.) ‘table’ and *bord* (f.) ‘table’ with the inflecting adjective *brwnt* ‘dirty’:

```
    | m.                 |  f
-------------------------+--------------------
sg. | y bwrdd brwnt      | y ford front
pl. | y byrddau bryntion | y bordydd bryntion
----+--------------------+--------------------
```

Both *bwrdd ~ byrddau*, *bord ~ bordydd*, and *brwnt/bront ~ bryntion/bryntion* inflect for number here, but the article is uninflected. Apart from the regular gender inflection of adjectives modifying feminine nouns being subject to soft mutation, *brwnt* also has a specifically feminine form *bront*.

Answer (score 4):

Maltese exhibits these properties (which you might have expected after @fdb's answer since Maltese is the "Arabic" European language).

The definite article in Maltese is **il-** and does not change according to number or gender. I can't quite claim that it's *invariable* as it changes to **ic-** in front of a **c**, **ix-** in front of an **x** and so on for the so-called *sun letters*, but to me at least that's a little like English choosing to use **an** before vowels and **a** otherwise.

Nouns and adjectives are inflected for both number and gender: *the dog* in Maltese is **il-kelb** and the dogs are **il-klieb**.  (I was going to use cat -- **qattus** -- but then I'd have to explain how to pronounce that **q**).  A big dog is **il-kelb il-kbir** and "big dogs" are **il-klieb il-kbar**.  For many nouns there is also a third plural form into indicate there are exactly two of something

Comment: In Maltese (as in all modern Arabic dialects) nouns and adjectives are inflected for number, but not for case. There are no cases.

Comment: @fdb Quite right!  I meant gender -- I'll correct it now.  Thanks :)

Comment: No cases? I thought (at least Quranic) Arabic had nominative/accusative cases.

Comment: @Wilson Maltese definitely doesn't inflect for case; I don't know about other Arabic languages I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm wondering how widespread this is in Semitic languages. Biblical Hebrew fits the criteria as well. May write up an answer about this after some more research.

Answer (score 1):

For typological questions you can consult related databases, such as [The World Atlas of Language Structures](http://wals.info/) (the most widely used), [AUTOTYP](http://www.autotyp.uzh.ch/), [SSWL](http://sswl.railsplayground.net/) to get the answer. As mentioned, Arabic might be one such example.

Comment: Quoting the important online resources is a good thing. You can improve your answer by giving some more detail on how to find languages with the properties in question by using one or more of the resources.